# Extending Shopify's collection properties

Tags: shopify

A [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) collection can have an associated image and description. Is it possible to add a second image, collection logo, to the collection properties?

Comment: it is possible creating a private app and using javascript ajax to load images for any collection validating by collection_id

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a second image using Shopify's web interface either to the [SmartCollection](http://docs.shopify.com/api/smartcollection) or [CustomCollection](http://docs.shopify.com/api/customcollection) resources. You can indeed use [metafields](http://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield) to any of those resources to add any data you wish.